# Where does Smartgit store project settings on Windows 7?

Tags: smartgit

I was happy to find that upgrading to the new version of Smargit and removing the previous one, it still keeps my projects settings (as expected).

Yet, I did not found this setting stored in the users AppData folder. So, I was wondering where does Smartgit store project settings on Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On all Windows platforms, settings are stored in `%APPDATA%\syntevo\SmartGit\<version>`, unless you have specified a different location by using `-Dsmartgit.settings` in `bin\smartgithg.vmoptions`.

Comment: I did not find it there. I made a search for `*smartgit*` under `C:\Users` folder and it did not return any result. And I did not specify any different location either. I just followed the standard installation of SmartGit.

Comment: What's your %APPDATA%? `echo %APPDATA%`

Comment: It is `C:\Users\mcarvalho\AppData\Roaming`. And, yest I found there the SmartGit settings. Thank you